# How to call api after screen is loaded react native

Tags: react-native

I am developing app using react native, and i have api call that retrieve json. How i can call another api in home screen immediately after it is loaded, this api i want to use for storing json data in order to use it in another screen, because i do not want the user to wait if he clicks.

The home.js that display the home screen is :

```
export class HomeScreen extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            data: null,
            isError: false,
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        getArticles().then(data => {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                data: data
            })
        }, error => {
            Alert.alert("Error", "Something happend, please try again")
        })
    }
```

The function that gets articles:

```
export async function getArticles(){

    try {
        let articles = await fetch(``);
        let result = await articles.json();
        return result;

    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
}
```

Can you recommend also tutorials or docs about cashing json response ?.

Comment: What's wrong with your code at the moment? Calling your API in `componentDidMount` is the correct way to achieve this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of these 3 third-party libraries to cache the response

1. [Redux] https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started
2. [React Native Async Storage] https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage
3. [Context API] https://www.taniarascia.com/using-context-api-in-react/

You can call as many APIs in the componentDidMount. But if the second API is dependent on the first API then call second API in the **then** function